# ReactJS setting css classes based on props

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react to build a list app, and I want to add css classes based on different events. I figured I could easily add/remove classes based on passing different props to the component. The list items are sent from the store, and handled in the container, and the translation of different props into css classes is done in the components.

At the moment I create an array of all the items in the container, like this:

```
this.state = {
    items: this.props.items.map(function(item){
        return <ItemWrapper><item/></ItemWrapper>
    })
}
```

Then, in ItemWrapper, for example:

```
(if this.props.isActive) {
    return <li className='active'>{this.props.children}</li>
}
```

So whenever I want to add the 'active' class to an item, I set the "isActive" prop on it.

But because all items are saved in an array in the container state, I have to create a copy of the array every time I want to change the "isActive" prop, so clearly not a great solution, especially as the list grows.

I've thought of saving each item under its own key in the state, but then if I want to add classes via timing events - say add a class to one element and remove it from another every set period of time - it becomes difficult.

What's the most efficient way to manage these class changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have to store components in your state, just store an array of objects and the active index, this is how I do :

the parent component state :

```
{
    children : [{name : 'first', id : 1 }, {name : 'second', id : 2 }, ... ],
    active : 1
}
```

in a render method of the parent component :

```
this.state.children.map( (child, i) => {
        const active = ( i == this.state.active )
        return <Child key={i} active={active}>{child.name}</Child>
    }
})
```

the child component :

```
const Child = (props) => { 
    const active = props.active ? 'active' : '';
    return <div className={active}>{props.children}</div>
}
```

And it seems that you are using a Redux store, in this case avoid using `this.state = ...` and `this.setState()`, instead use `connect` from `react-redux` in your parent component with a mapStateToProps function.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I used a variation on this solution, and it works. I need to do some more manipulation on the state.active index, and see how it works when it's being set via different events.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ternary operator to do this easily:

```
<li className={this.props.isActive ? 'isActive' : ''}>{this.props.children}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [classNames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) package. It's a simple javascript utility for conditionally joining classNames together.

```
classNames('foo', 'bar'); // => 'foo bar'
classNames('foo', { bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'
classNames({ 'foo-bar': true }); // => 'foo-bar'
classNames({ 'foo-bar': false }); // => ''
classNames({ foo: true }, { bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'
classNames({ foo: true, bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'

// lots of arguments of various types
classNames('foo', { bar: true, duck: false }, 'baz', { quux: true }); // => 'foo bar baz quux'

// other falsy values are just ignored
classNames(null, false, 'bar', undefined, 0, 1, { baz: null }, ''); // => 'bar 1'
```

**Real-world example:**

```
/* components/submit-button.js */
import { Component } from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames/bind';
import styles from './submit-button.css';

let cx = classNames.bind(styles);

export default class SubmitButton extends Component {
  render () {
    let text = this.props.store.submissionInProgress ? 'Processing...' : 'Submit';
    let className = cx({
      base: true,
      inProgress: this.props.store.submissionInProgress,
      error: this.props.store.errorOccurred,
      disabled: this.props.form.valid,
    });
    return <button className={className}>{text}</button>;
  }
};
```